# we lack wings prevents VS lack of wings prevents

Tags: relative-clauses

I got a bit disturbed when I read sentence in a book Flow by Mihaly Csikszzentmihalyi:

> The first fact does not entail the second any more than the fact that we lack wings prevents us from flying.

Is it correct? Shouldn't it be

> The first fact does not entail the second any more than the fact that lack of wings prevents us from flying.

Comment: "That we lack wings" is a relative clause describing the noun "fact". What kind of fact? "The fact [that we lack wings]".

Comment: @CopperKettle thanks ;) If you like you can post it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood the original sentence.

That sentence posits four facts: two causes and two consequences ...

```
CAUSES                           CONSEQUENCES
A: the first fact                B: the second fact  
C: the fact that we lack wings   D: we cannot fly
```

Now, *C prevents us from flying* is equivalent to saying that *C entails that we cannot fly*, so we can parse the relationship posited like this:

```
          not (A entails B)
any more than (C entails D)
```

That is, Truth<sub>(A entails B)</sub> ≦ Truth<sub>(C entails D)</sub>.

But Truth<sub>(C entails D)</sub> = 0 (false)—we **can** fly (in airplanes) even though we don't have wings.

Therefore Truth<sub>(A entails B)</sub> ≦ 0, and (A entails B) is also false—which is what the author is asserting: "The first fact does not entail the second fact".

Now look at the end of your rewrite:

> the fact that lack of wings prevents us from flying.

The subordinator *that* requires a full 'sentence', a clause including both a subject noun phrase and a verb phrase, as its complement. In the original, the complement is *we lack wings*; that is what is asserted as fact C.

When you change *we lack wings* to *lack of wings*, you have changed the verb *lack* to a noun. Now we have to understand *lack of wings* as the complement's subject noun, and *prevents us from flying* as the complement's verb phrase. You have combined fact C, the entailment, and consequence D into a single fact: *We cannot fly because lack of wings prevents it*.

```
CAUSES                           CONSEQUENCES
A: the first fact                B: the second fact  
C: we cannot fly
```

But with only three terms, we now have a very different syntactic relationship:

```
          not (A entails B)
any more than (C)
```

Something's missing here. We assume that something's been ellipted in the second term, either the subject or the object of the entailment:

```
          not (A entails B)
any more than (A entails C)
```

or 
              not (A entails B)
    any more than (C entails B)

Without explicit knowledge of A and B we don't have enough information to decide which you mean; but in either case you've created an entirely new assertion:

> The first fact does not entail the second any more than the fact that lack of wings prevents us from flying entails the second.

or

> The first fact does not entail the second any more than the first fact entails the fact that lack of wings prevents us from flying.

Comment: I like your way of making truth as function :)